# Magento use associated simple product image for configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images, simple-product

Is it possible to make Magento use the image of a simple attached product on configurable products?

So if one of the simple products have an image, add it to the configurable product, else use placeholder image?

We have +50k products coming in via csv and new ones being added every day, but the configurable product has no image from the csv. So we need to do this for the existing database and for new products, that are being added.

We are using v1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below article, may be it will help to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200169/how-to-use-simple-product-images-for-configurable-product-images

Thanks.